# How to call a function outside of an emitted event call function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I apologize if this is unclear, it's late and I don't know how best to explain it.

I'm using an event emitter to pass data from a server response to a function inside of a separate class in another file, but when trying to use methods in those classes, the `this` keyword obviously doesn't work (because in this scenario, `this` refers to the server event emitter) - how would I reference a function within the class itself? I've provided code to help illustrate my point a bit better

ServiceClass.js

```
class StreamService {
  /**
     *
     * @param {} database
     * @param {Collection<Guild>} guilds
  */
  constructor (database, guilds,) {
      .....
      twitchListener.on('live', this.sendLiveAlert) // fire test method when we get a notification
      // if there are streamers to monitor, being monitoring
      winston.info('Stream service initialized')
  }

  ..............

  async get (url, params = null, headers = this.defaultHeaders) {
    // check oauth token
    const expirationDate = this.token.expires_in || 0
    if (expirationDate <= Date.now() || !this.token) await this.getAccessToken()
    // build URL
    const index = 0
    let paramsString = ''
    for (const [key, value] of params.entries()) {
      if (index === 0) {
        paramsString += `?${key}=${value}`
      } else {
        paramsString += `&${key}=${value}`
      }
    }
    const res = await fetch(url + paramsString, { method: 'GET', headers: headers })
    if (!res.ok) {
      winston.error(`Error performing GET request to ${url}`)
      return null
    }
    return await res.json()
  }

  async sendLiveAlert(streamTitle, streamURL, avatar, userName, gameId, viewerCount, thumbnail, startDateTime) {
    // get game name first (no headers needed)
    const params = new Map()
    params.set('id', gameId)
    const gameData = await this.get('https://api.twitch.tv/heliix/games', params, this.defaultHeaders)
    if(gameData) {
      // get webhook and send message to channel
      const webhookClient = new WebhookClient('755641606555697305', 'OWZvI01kUUf4AAIR9uv2z4CxRse3Ik8b0LKOluaOYKmhE33h0ypMLT0JJm3laomlZ05o')
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${userName} just went live on Twitch!`)
        .setURL(streamURL)
        .setThumbnail(avatar)
        .addFields(
          { name: 'Now Playing', value: gameData.data[0].name },
          { name: 'Stream Title', value: streamTitle }
        )
        .setImage(thumbnail)
    }
    webhookClient.send('Webhook test', embed)
  }
}
```

Server.js

```
class TwitchWebhookListener extends EventEmitter {
    ......................
    // Routes
    server
      .post((req, res) => {
        console.log('Incoming POST request on /webhooks')
              ............................
                const data = req.body.data[0]
                if(!this.streamerLiveStatus.get(data.user_id) && data.type === 'live') {
                  // pass request body to bot for processing
                  this.emit(
                    'live',
                    data.title, // stream title
                    `https://twitch.tv/${data.user_name}`, // channel link
                    `https://avatar.glue-bot.xyz/twitch/${data.user_name}`, // streamer avatar
                    data.user_name,
                    data.game_id,
                    data.viewer_count,
                    data.thumbnail_url,
                    data.started_at // do we need this?
                  )
                }
                break
              default:
                res.send(`Unknown webhook for ${req.params.id}`)
                break
            }
          } else {
            console.log('The Signature did not match')
            res.send('Ok')
          }
        } else {
          console.log('It didn\'t seem to be a Twitch Hook')
          res.send('Ok')
        }
      })
  }
}

const listener = new TwitchWebhookListener()
listener.listen()

module.exports = listener
```

Within the `sendLiveAlert` method, I'm trying to call the get method of the StreamService class - but because it's called directly via the emitter within `server.js`, `this` refers specifically to the `Server.js` class - is there any way I can use `StreamService.get()`? I could obviously just rewrite the code inside the method itself, but that seems unnecessary when its right there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
twitchListener.on('live', this.sendLiveAlert)
```

to this:

```
twitchListener.on('live', this.sendLiveAlert.bind(this))
```

Or, you could also do this:

```
twitchListener.on('live', (...args) => {
    this.sendLiveAlert(...args);
});
```

With `.bind()` it creates a function wrapper that resets the proper value of `this` for you.  In the case of the arrow function, it preserves the lexical value of `this` for you.

Comment: Simultaneous answers. I could delete mine, if you handle the `args` in your second option function.

Comment: @RahulBhobe - I added in the args.

Comment: Is it my imagination or have margins between code blocks and text in answers all of a sudden increased?

Comment: Ah, I see! I was thinking it was a scoping issue I just wasn’t sure how to handle it. This worked like a charm!